# NumberPicker can't read keyboard's input

Tags: android, numberpicker

As title, I open a number picker and want to input a number. But whatever I input, the number picker has no changes. It is  supposed to enter a number and use the value to set amount but I cannot change its value. How can I use it correctly?

Here is my code:

```
private void loadAddBtnContent(){
        TextView add_to_cart = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart);
        if ( cart.checkInCart(pid) ){
            add_to_cart.setText("in Cart ("+cart.getProductAmount(pid)+")");
            add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){               
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {                   
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(pdActivity);
                    NumberPicker amountPicker = new NumberPicker(pdActivity);

                    builder.setView(amountPicker);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Change", new addCartListener(amountPicker)).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                    builder.show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            add_to_cart.setText("Add to cart");
            add_to_cart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){               
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(pdActivity);
                    NumberPicker amountPicker = new NumberPicker(pdActivity);
                    amountPicker.setMinValue(1);

                    builder.setView(amountPicker);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new addCartListener(amountPicker)).setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                    builder.show();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private class addCartListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
        private NumberPicker amountPicker;

        public addCartListener(NumberPicker amountPicker){
            this.amountPicker = amountPicker;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(which){
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                amountPicker.clearFocus();
                cart.setInCartAmount(product, amountPicker.getValue());
                break;
            case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                break;
            }
            loadAddBtnContent();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I found something..."The problem is that the editText will update the internal value only if you change the focus which doesn't occur every time ", is it related to my problem??

Comment: News, I can only set '0' in the keyboard but cannot set others. I press '1-9' but no response

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using different **devices** and **emulators**.

I had the same problem with an emulator, i changed it and tried other devices, they all worked.

Comment: Yeah, try it on other emulators.